# Libstream change source from camera to screen everything need to capture and transfer

Tags: android, sockets, libstreaming

i want to make an application which can capture the screen of one android phone and transfer to other phone over internet i try to use `MediaRecorder API` something like this

```
mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
            mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(parcelWrite.getFileDescriptor());



            mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT);
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
            mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(999999999);
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(100);
            int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
            int orientation = ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation);
            mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(orientation);
            mMediaRecorder.prepare();
            mMediaRecorder.start();
```

here `MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE` works to capture my screen i try to transfer with socket stream on next end but its can be play because it need complete video to receive first so for this purpose i find libstream api which work on `RTSP/RTP` and work as require for me but it transmit camera i want to transfer screen but unable to find where i need to changes which class need to overrite for this purpose please guide me how to change the libstream api source from

> camera to screen

Comment: Sorry i need to transfer over wifi not want to use internet